# How to access a subpage (same url different content) with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Using BeautifulSoup on Python, I'm trying to scrape a subpage of this page

`https://www.mmorpg-stat.eu/0_fiche_alliance.php?pays=5&ftr=500208.all&univers=_146`

More precisely, the subpage titled [image]

The problem is that by clicking on that button, the url doesn't change (is this called a subpage? If not what is it?) so I cannot access that page with

```
url = '...'
requests.get(url)
```

Looking at the browser console, the button code is

```
<td width="250" align="center" valign="middle" class="Style1_f_j barre_joueur1 fond_56_1" style="cursor:pointer;text-transform: uppercase" onclick="fcache12('faCacher');fcache13('ffond_gris');document.form1_2date.statview.value='2';document.forms['form1_2date'].submit();return false;">
                 <span style="color:#ffffff;">&nbsp;&nbsp;Other information</span>
</td>
```

All I can understand is that when clicked, the button calls some `fcache` method.

How to access the subpage?

Comment: where do you click on you code?

Comment: @Wonka what do you mean?

Comment: no, what do you means with your question?

Comment: How to access the content of the page that is reached when clicking on "Other information" via BeautifulSoup?

Comment: so, what you tried?

Comment: @soundwave See my answer below for some suggestions.

Comment: I just searched for similar problems but didn't find anything, I don't know what to do.

Comment: @soundwave The key is that clicking the button issues a POST request, not a GET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> All I can understand is that when clicked, the button calls some fcache method.

```
onclick="fcache12('faCacher');fcache13('ffond_gris');document.form1_2date.statview.value='2';document.forms['form1_2date'].submit();return false;"
```

It actually calls two different methods: `fcache12()` and `fcache13()`. **And then it finds a form in the page and submits it**:

```
document.forms['form1_2date'].submit()
```

If you search `'form1_2date'`, you will find:

```
<form name="form1_2date" method="post">
```

So to simulate clicking on this button, you need to call `requests.post()` instead of `requests.get()`. You also need to determine the form values that should be passed in. These are determined by all of the `<input>` tags in the form.

Alternatively, you can use `selenium` or a similar library to simulate user interaction in a browser rather than trying to make the requests directly.

Comment: I can hear a "crack" in the Head's Op

Comment: @Wonka Do you mean "the OP's head"?

Comment: Yes, sometimes my spanish and english merge

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Thank you for help! I found out that the buttons "Main statistics", "Secondary statistics" and "Other information" have these different values: `statview.value='0'`, `statview.value='1'` and `statview.value='2'`. I wonder have I to write something like `requests.get(url, value='2')` to obtain information of the page "Other information"? EDIT I learned that I have to use `requests.post(url, data=params)` where `params` is a list of information such as `params = {'name': 'Budi', 'age': '24'}`, but in this case which are the information to be put in the list?

Comment: @soundwave First of all `{}` indicates a dictionary, not a list. Secondly, what you put in the dictionary is based off the `<input>` elements in the form. Specifically, the key is the `name` attribute of the `<input>` and the value is the `value` of the `<input>`.

Comment: Thank you, I don't understand in this case what is the `<input>` that you are talking about?

Comment: @soundwave You have to inspect the `<form>` and see what `<input>` elements it contains. You will need to include all of them.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice is this the right place to inspect the form? https://i.imgur.com/U7JAwfV.png

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I found 12 `<input>` inside the `<form name="form1_2date" method="post">`, what have I to do with them?

Comment: @soundwave You can use their `name` and `value` attributes to build the dictionary to send in your POST request.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice The first `<input>` is `<input name="keyf" id="keyf" type="hidden">`, does this mean that its entry in the dictionary is `{ 'keyf':'keyf':'hidden' }` ?

Comment: @soundwave You are correct that `'keyf'` is the key since that is the `name` of the `<input>`. However, you need to dig deeper to find the value it is set to. It might be set by some JavaScript somewhere. Also, note that two colons like have there doesn't make any sense. A dictionary is formed like this: `{'key1': value1, 'key2': value2}`, etc.

Comment: Thank you for long support, however I think this goes well beyond my skills. I will ask in a new answer how to do it.